# Creating events on latest Google Calendar API with Service Accounts

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have looked for many solutions here but they are old and don't have a clear answer to my problem. I have successfully created events using OAuth2 everything works perfectly. I am looking for the server to perform the authorization itself, which would allow it to avoid manual authorization each time.

I tried to use a service account to "impersonate" a user but it doesn't work. What I have read from Google is:

> **About authorization protocols:** Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported.

Furthermore, it states:

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access
>   users data without any manual authorization on their part. In **G Suite**
>   domains, the domain administrator can grant to the third party
>   applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred
>   as a domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this
>   way, domain administrators can use **service accounts with OAuth 2.0**.

And

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this scenario, you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end-user.

So, from what I have read, we have to have a G Suite account. The service account will be used for required functionality. Is this right? Do I really need a G Suite account? Is there any other way of handling a simple user **G Mail** account or even a service account?

Answer (score 0):

> The service account will be used for required functionality. Is this right?

Yes, indeed you DO need a service account for server to server authorization using oAuth 2.0 , [more information about that here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

> Do I really need a G Suite account? Is there any other way of handling a simple user G Mail account or even a service account?

No, you do not actually need to be a G Suite user for having a service account. You can create one through the Google Cloud console. [More information about how to do that here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount). You do not need to  grant G Suite domain-wide authority to the service account (and thus do not need a G Suite account) to achieve what you are looking for.